# Nodejs - Frisby testing

Tags: node.js

Node Script have to call a URL , and  get the response and use the some variable of the response to call the next url. is it possible?

in below example, i'm using token in other scripts.

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
    host: 'url' ,
    path: '/path',
    method: 'POST'
};
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    token="hi"; // to be populated by res
});
req.end();
exports.token = token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to export `token` before it exists. When you assign `token = "hi"`, that happens *after* the http request finishes and you get the response. What you want to do instead is `export` a function with a callback which returns your data from the url.

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
    host: 'url' ,
    path: '/path',
    method: 'POST'
};
exports.getToken = function (callback) {
    http.request(options, function(res) {
        callback(res);
    });
};
```

Then in your other module, you would have to call the `getToken` function passing it a callback function.

```
//I assume the above file is called tokenFinder.js
var tokenFinder = require('./tokenFinder');
var token;
tokenFinder.getToken(function (data) {
    token = data;
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer does not tell me how, using frisby, I can create a test based on the outcome of another test.

The example above is using "http", I wish I could find an example using frisby to do it.